# ¿Como ver una carpeta de imagenes con PHP si en mi host puse todos los permisos para el owner?

Tags: php, html, hosting

Hola ya pude proteger carpetas con hostinger quitando permisos a las carpetas mi idea es que tanto las imagenes como los archivos php no esten visibles al menos que se use codigo php como el siguiente, quiero que solo sean visibles para los clientes y trabajadoras por ejemplo

```
<img src="<?php if(isset($profile_picture)) echo $profile_picture; ?>" class="img img-rounded" heigth="60" width="60"/>
```

Este codigo me funciona perfecto pero al deshabilitar los permisos deja de funcionar :/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

no hagas eso, trata esto

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Crea un archivo .htaccess e incrusta `RewriteEngine On` ya que cuando bloqueas los permisos directamente desde el cpanel también bloqueas que lo pueda leer el php.

Comment: Calculo que hablarás de `RewriteEngine On`, pero esa línea por sí sola no soluciona nada.